# ImportError: No module named 'passlib.totp'

Tags: python, ubuntu, pgadmin

I have problem when I try to install pgAdmin4 on ubuntu 16 :( and `pip install passlib` don't help me. Somebody knows how to fix it?

````
    from pgadmin.model import db, User, Version, ServerGroup, Server, \
  File "/usr/share/pgadmin4/web/pgadmin/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from flask_security import Security, SQLAlchemyUserDatastore, current_user
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask_security/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .core import Security, RoleMixin, UserMixin, AnonymousUser, current_user
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask_security/core.py", line 60, in <module>
    from .totp import Totp
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask_security/totp.py", line 12, in <module>
    from passlib.totp import TOTP, TokenError
ImportError: No module named 'passlib.totp'
dpkg: error processing package pgadmin4-apache2 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up python-passlib (1.7.1-1.pgdg16.04+1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 pgadmin4-apache2
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)```
````

Comment: did you find answer to this query?

Answer (score 2):

Try this, This worked for me.

```
**sudo pip install "passlib==1.7.2"**
```

ref: - https://nomodulenamed.com/m/passlib.totp

Comment: I facing this for a long moment when installing pgadmin4 `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'passlib.totp'`, but this answer figure it out, thanks Dude :)